# Generate all possible (public internet) IPV4 Address combinations in Python

Tags: python

My goal is to loop through all possible ipv4 address that could be used in the web (like a computer, IoT device, etc, just not private networks) combinations in Python.
As I was searching, I found a couple of solutions:

1:
Use a while loop and loop through the possible combinations (however, not sure this would stop, I ported this from a stackoverflow in C that I now cannot find):

```py
i = 0
while(i != -1):

    b1 = (i >> 24) & 0xff
    b2 = (i >> 16) & 0xff
    b3 = (i >>  8) & 0xff
    b4 = (i >> 4) & 0xff

    i += 1
```

2:
Using a `for` loop:
I found this code in a bash question: [bash - Generate all possible ipv4 addresses using seq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65066637/14465957)

(c code):

```
int main() {
  int h, i, j, k;

  for (h = 0; h < 256; h++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 256; k++) {
          printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", h, i, j, k);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? Both of these implementations allow 0.0.0.0 and private ips to be valid, so these are not solutions I want at the moment.

Comment: Both solutions are roughly equivalent.  You're probably going to have to explain better what addresses you want to filter out.

Comment: If you were really strict, it is an impossible task. E.g. X.Y.Z.127 is a broadcast address in a network with prefix /25, but it is a host address if the prefix were the usual /24.

Comment: There is no pattern or simple rule, you have to filter all these out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

Comment: @FrankYellin basically, anything that is not a public address.

Comment: @VPfB i found this link which shows all ranges of public ips: [public](https://www.avg.com/en/signal/public-vs-private-ip-address)
Could I use this alongside something like [an ip range generator](https://tkit.dev/2011/09/11/how-to-generate-an-ip-range-list-in-python/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify the 4 nested loops. This is incomplete, just the basic idea:

```
for a in range(1, 224): # skip 0.0.0.0/8 reserved,
                        # 224.0.0.0/4 multicast, 240.0.0.0/4 reserved
    if a == 10:
        continue # skip 10.0.0.0/8 private
    if a == 127:
        continue # skip 127.0.0.0/8 loopback
    for b in range(256):
        if a == 172 and 16 <= b < 32:
            continue # skip 172.16.0.0/12 private
        if a == 192 and b == 168:
            continue # skip 192.168.0.0/16 private
        for c in range(256):
            for d in range(1, 255): # omit network x.x.x.0 and broadcast x.x.x.255
                pass # now you have a.b.c.d
```

As I commented, the validity of some host addresses depends on the netmask. For a complete list of reserved addresses visit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#IPv4

Answer (score 2):

You can use ipaddress, it's in the standard library. is_private will exclude RFC1918 addresses (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16) as well as some others.

```
import ipaddress

all_ipv4 = ipaddress.ip_network('0.0.0.0/0')

for host in all_ipv4.hosts():
    if host.is_private:
        continue
    print(host) #do your thing here
```